# What is a preferred way to sort strings numerically in MySQL, using string's numeric component?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sorting

I have a column of strings like so:

```
ABC-10
ABC-20
ABC-40
...
ABC-130
ABC-410
```

I wish to sort them via number.

I know of two ways:

```
SELECT * from table 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '-', -1) + 0;
```

and

```
SELECT * from table 
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(model, LENGTH(model) - 4) as unsigned);
```

Both appear to give the same results.  Is one more preferred than another?

Comment: I'd prefer to store the prefix and the number in two diferent columns.

Comment: Preference would be determined by performance, in this case.  Can you benchmark with a tool like HeidiSQL?  You'd need a lot of records to see any performance difference, I'd expect.

Comment: The first approach seems more flexible, though you should probably cast the result to an unsigned int.

Comment: `substring(model, 5) + 0`

Comment: In my case the strings represent a part number, and the part number does not fit into any particular pattern.  i.e. there are strings like `ZXFF-VV-4-HPK`, but in my case I only need to sort the ones that fit into pattern `ABC-[0-9]+`.  Also I am guessing that `+ 0` does an implicit cast and the first way is more flexible, in case alpha part of the string changes

Comment: But you can't use an index if you sort by an expression.

Answer (score 0):

When the numeric string is short, it is preferred to use the first method. The cast will take a lot longer than ordering a 4 digit string

When the numeric string is long (it has to be very long), then the first method is preferred, because the cast won't take as long as ordering strings with so many caharcters. Numbers are very easy to order in comparison to strings